# How to disable full screen on html video in LinkedIn app browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple video player, everything works perfectly except when the user open the player inside LinkedIn app browser it open in full screen mode

Is there any way to play a video inline on iPhone when using the in-app browser without going fullscreen?

Here is my HTML 5 video tag.

```
<video id="videoplayer" playsinline="1" webkit-playsinline="1" muted="" autoplay="" movieid="1" src="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/videos/mena.mp4?rand=0.16011310198007833" style="opacity: 1;" class="ended">
</video>
```

Note : solution can be using javascript or jquery etc